# Why is http.Client{} prefixed with &?

Tags: pointers, go, methods, struct

I am learning Go and I am reading Go's official documentation about [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), and I write following code from doc for test:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, _ := client.Get("http://example.com")

    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

`http.Client` is a struct, but I do not know why there is a `&` pointer prefixed. I think creating a `http.Client` reference is not necessary. And why does the `client` variable have a `Get` method? I am reading the source code of `net/http`, it defines the `Client` struct below:

```
type Client struct {
    Transport RoundTripper
    CheckRedirect func(req *Request, via []*Request) error
    Jar CookieJar
    Timeout time.Duration
}
```

The `Client` struct does not have a `Get` method defined; why does the `client` variable have a `Get` method?

Comment: Why down vote this question, Please give some reason so I will attention to ask.

Comment: Because it shows zero research effort before asking the question. This is covered thoroughly in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and [tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1).

Comment: But the `method receiver` did not mentioned in tour, this is a different concept with another languages that learner misunderstand. And pass value directly to function parameter is just a copy without specified with a pointer did not mentioned in tour too(I never using a language that doing a http request using pointer directly, ruby, java, python, elixir...). And reading spec is boring and long for learning a new language. And I do not think a fresher question is no valuable, you can see the the last one answer is wrong too, this meaning some people still do not understand this language too.

Comment: [Methods are covered extensively in the tour.](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) Please make some effort to figure things out for yourself before posting for help from the community.

Comment: @Adrian, Fine, That's me fault, Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would really take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to get a feeling of the language and its basic syntax first.

The type declaration you quoted only contains the *fields* of the struct, but not its *methods*. Methods are defined elsewhere, like functions but with a *receiver* added which designates the type they belong to. For example the definition of `Client.Get()` method is this:

```
func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error) {
    req, err := NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return c.Do(req)
}
```

The part before the method name is called the receiver, and that designates the type the method belogns to (`*Client` in this example). See [Spec: Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) for more details.

The `&` is an [address operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), it takes the address of its operand. In this case the local variable `client` will be of type [`*http.Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client). `http.Client{}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) which creates a value of the struct type `http.Client`, and `&` takes the address of the anonymous variable where this struct value is stored:

> [Taking the address](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) of a composite literal generates a pointer to a unique [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) initialized with the literal's value.

It is used so that the `client` variable will be a pointer to an `http.Client` value, one that is encouraged to be shared and reused:

> The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

And if `client` is a pointer, you are free to pass it around to other functions, only the pointer value will be copied, not the pointed `http.Client` struct, so the struct itself (the `http.Client` value) will be reused. Should you not use a pointer, if you would pass it to other functions, the struct itself would be copied and not reused.

Note that in this simple example it doesn't really matter, as even though all methods of `http.Client` are declared with pointer receiver, you can still call pointer methods on non-pointer variables, as `client.Get()` would be a shorthand for `(&client).Get()`. This is mentioned in [Spec: Calls:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> If `x` is [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`.

So even though the `&` address operator is not needed in this simple example, it's good to keep the habit of using it, should the example grow or should you write code where this does matter (e.g. you pass around the created client).