# Tour of Go, difference between & and no & when referring to a Vector struct

Tags: pointers, go, struct, pass-by-reference

I know using & symbol address the address of the stored value, but as I'm going the "Tour of Go", in the sections where they introducing pointers and special receivers, they have code as follow for referring to a Vector struct to scale and get the absolute value as shown:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
    v.X = v.X * f
    v.Y = v.Y * f
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := &Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Printf("Before scaling: %+v, Abs: %v\n", v, v.Abs())
    v.Scale(5)
    fmt.Printf("After scaling: %+v, Abs: %v\n", v, v.Abs())
}
```

With an output of:

```
Before scaling: &{X:3 Y:4}, Abs: 5
After scaling: &{X:15 Y:20}, Abs: 25
```

But if I change the main function call to have `v := Vector{3.4}` instead of `v:= &Vector{3.4}`, I get the same output. Is it better practice to refer to the memeory address in this case? More of a conceptual circumstance I don't seem to understand.

Comment: See [Why is http.Client{} prefixed with &?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751608/why-is-http-client-prefixed-with/45751833#45751833)

Answer (score 2):

You will not get the exact same output, notice that the output no longer indicates that you've passed a pointer (the `&` is missing):

```
Before scaling: {X:3 Y:4}, Abs: 5
After scaling: {X:15 Y:20}, Abs: 25
```

The reason you can still call the absolute value method is because Go implicitly takes the address of `v` for you when it sees that the method exists on a pointer type but you've used the struct directly since it is always possible to take the address of the struct and derive a method call on the pointer receiver.

For more information, see the "Method expressions" section of the Go spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions

There isn't really enough information in this specific instance to tell you whether it's good or bad practice to use the struct value or always pass a pointer around. This is very dependent on the situation, the size of the struct, whether you want your value stack or heap allocated, and any number of other factors. However, for most programs it probably won't make a difference and I'd advise that it's not worth worrying about early on as you learn Go.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, really helped out.

Comment: Glad I could be of service! If this does answer your question, be sure to hit the big green checkmark to mark it as the answer and help  anyone else searching for this in the future. Thanks!